# Getting Associative Array Keys

Tags: php

How can i get array keys up to specified key. 
I have array like

```
Array
(
    [101] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Id] => 56
                    [Val] => 15.25
                )
         )
     [112] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Id] => 56
                    [Val] => 15.25
                )
         )
      [223] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Id] => 56
                    [Val] => 15.25
                )
         )
       [104] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Id] => 56
                    [Val] => 15.25
                )
         )
     [186] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Id] => 56
                    [Val] => 15.25
                )
         )
)
```

And i have key "104" , how can i get the array keys up to 104 only i.e,101,112,223 keys only  without looping

Comment: What's your problem with looping?

Answer (score 4):

A simple foreach

```
$key = 104;
$values = array();

foreach($inputs as $k => $v) {
   if($k == $key) break;
   $values[] = $v;
}

var_dump($values);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
$upTo104 = array();

foreach($array as $key => $value){
    $upTo104[] = $value;
    if ($key === 104) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($mainArray  as $key=>$value)
{
  if($key == 104)
  break;
  $getarray[] = $value;
}
```